# How to automate the seasonal adjustment using X12 Arima

Tags: gretl

I am very new on Gretl and I need to do the seasonal adjustment of the same time serie every week. Currently, I am doing it manually, so I would like to know if there is any code that I could write in order to automate this process, importing the file from excel and doing the X12 arima for variables on columns B,C and D. I would appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Please, try this:

```
open "C:/your_file.xlsx"

series x1_sa = deseas(x1)
series x2_sa = deseas(x2)
series x3_sa = deseas(x3)
```

Where `x1`, `x2` and `x3` are the names of your variables.